# Fast way to iterate over sparse numpy array but only where elements are 1

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have an array representing a light source in space made as such:

```
source2D = np.zeros((256, 256))
```

with any amount of the pixels = 1. An example I have is a point source which is generated by:

```
source2D[126:128, 126:128] = 1
```

And I am running a monte carlo simulation which shoots a ray from each part of the array where the value = 1. Currently I am iterating over the entire array but I would save a lot of time by only picking out the elements where array = 1 and iterating over them. I should add that this function should be made to accept a generic 256x256 where any elements could be set to 1, so cropping the array is not an option. What is the fastest way to do this? I am also using tensorflow so if there is an implementation using that, that would also be an option

Right now my code looks somethinglike this:

```
while pc < 1000000:
    pc+=1
                
    # Randomize x and y as coordinates on source
    x = np.random.randint(0, source2D.shape[0])  # 0 to 255 for this example
    y = np.random.randint(0, source2D.shape[1])  # 0 to 255 for this example

    # Shoot raycast from x,y to point on detector
```

Comment: Use `np.nonzero` to get the indices of all the `'1's

Answer (score 0):

Solved with hpaulj's comment:

```
source2D = np.zeros((256, 256))  # Testing with point source
source2D[126:128, 126:128] = 1
nonzero_entries = np.nonzero(source2D)

i = np.random.choice(nonzero_entries[0]) 
j = np.random.choice(nonzero_entries[1])
```